# How do you do crossed lines using tikz-feynman?

Tags: tikz-feynman

I am trying to draw the Feynman diagram where the momenta are crossed over on the final state particles from the diagram encoded here.

```
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=i1 to a]{
f1[particle=\(\Bar{\psi}\)]--[anti fermion, momentum=\(p_2\)]b--[scalar, momentum=\(p_2'\)]f2[particle=\(\phi\)],
i1[particle=\(\psi\)]--[fermion, momentum=\(p_1\)]a--[scalar, momentum=\(p_1'\)]i2[particle=\(\phi\)],
b--[anti fermion, reversed momentum=\(p_1-p_1'\)]a,
i1--[opacity=0]f1,
i2--[opacity=0]f2,
};
```

I tried adding another vertex as follows, but it leaves a kink in the lines. Is there another way of doing this?

```
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=i1 to a]{
i1[particle=\(\psi\)]--[fermion, momentum=\(p_1\)]a--[scalar]a1--[scalar, momentum=\(p_1'\)]i2[particle=\(\phi\)],
f1[particle=\(\Bar{\psi}\)]--[anti fermion, momentum=\(p_2\)]b--[scalar]a1--[scalar, momentum'=\(p_2'\)]f2[particle=\(\phi\)],
b--[anti fermion]a,
i1--[opacity=0]f1,
i2--[opacity=0]f2,
};
```

Edit:
[image]

I am trying to make the second diagram have straight, scalar lines which cross

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean, please see [this](https://jpellis.me/projects/tikz-feynman/) page.

Comment: I personally draw, if I use this package, the diagrams without the layout algorithms, i.e. place the vertices by hand. According to my experience most diagrams are actually not easy to obtain with these layout mechanisms, which, after all, were not designed to draw Feynman graphs. Plus you cannot upload them to the arXiv, which currently does not support `lualatex`. So I recommend placing the vertices by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's recall how one solves this in `feynmp`. There you can use `phantoms` to add invisible propagators, and `\fmffreeze` to freeze the diagram at some point. We can do the analogous things in `tikz-feynman`. `phantom` gets mapped to `opacity=0`, and in a way `\fmffreeze` is emulated by putting the additional stuff in an `overlay` picture such that it does not influence the layout algorithm. `rubout`, which I implemented in a suggested alternative to your diagrams, is also very much inspired by `feynmp`, which IMHO still produces the most aesthetically pleasing Feynman diagrams.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\tikzset{rubout/.style={preaction={draw=white,line width=3pt}}}
\begin{document}

\subsection*{Your diagram}
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=i1 to a]{
f1[particle=\(\Bar{\psi}\)]--[anti fermion, momentum=\(p_2\)]b--[scalar, momentum=\(p_2'\)]f2[particle=\(\phi\)],
i1[particle=\(\psi\)]--[fermion, momentum=\(p_1\)]a--[scalar, momentum=\(p_1'\)]i2[particle=\(\phi\)],
b--[anti fermion, reversed momentum=\(p_1-p_1'\)]a,
i1--[opacity=0]f1,
i2--[opacity=0]f2,
};

\subsection*{Your diagram crossed}
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=i1 to a,remember picture]{
f1[particle=\(\Bar{\psi}\)]--[anti fermion, momentum=\(p_2\)]b--[opacity=0]f2[particle=\(\phi\)],
i1[particle=\(\psi\)]--[fermion, momentum=\(p_1\)]a--[opacity=0]i2[particle=\(\phi\)],
b--[anti fermion, reversed momentum'=\(p_1-p_2'\)]a,
i1--[opacity=0]f1,
i2--[opacity=0]f2,
};

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\begin{feynman}
\path (b) -- (i2) coordinate[midway] (b1)
(a) -- (f2) coordinate[midway] (a1);
\diagram*{
(b) --[scalar] (b1) -- [scalar,momentum'={\(p_1'\)}] (i2),
(a) --[scalar] (a1) -- [scalar,momentum={\(p_2'\)}] (f2)
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage

\subsection*{An alternative to your diagram}
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=i1 to i2]{
f1[particle=\(\Bar{\psi}\)]--[anti fermion, momentum=\(p_2\)]b--[scalar,
momentum'=\(p_2'\)]f2[particle=\(\phi\)],
i1[particle=\(\psi\)]--[fermion, momentum=\(p_1\)]a--[scalar, momentum=\(p_1'\)]i2[particle=\(\phi\)],
b--[anti fermion, reversed momentum'=\(p_1-p_1'\)]a,
};

\subsection*{An alternative to your diagram crossed}
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=i1 to i2,remember picture]{
f1[particle=\(\Bar{\psi}\)]--[anti fermion, momentum=\(p_2\)]b--[scalar,
opacity=0]f2[particle=\(\phi\)],
i1[particle=\(\psi\)]--[fermion, momentum=\(p_1\)]a--[scalar,opacity=0]i2[particle=\(\phi\)],
b--[anti fermion, reversed momentum'=\(p_1-p_2'\)]a,
};

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\begin{feynman}
\path (b) -- (i2) coordinate[midway] (b1)
(a) -- (f2) coordinate[midway] (a1);
\diagram*{
(b) --[scalar] (b1) -- [scalar,momentum={\(p_1'\)}] (i2),
(a) --[scalar,rubout] (a1) -- [scalar,momentum'={\(p_2'\)}] (f2)
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, processing with **Lualatex**.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=i1 to a]{
i1[particle=\(\psi\)]--[fermion, momentum=\(p_1\)]a--[scalar, momentum=\(p_1'\)]i2[particle=\(\phi\)],
f1[particle=\(\Bar{\psi}\)]--[anti fermion, momentum=\(p_2\)]b--[scalar, momentum=\(p_2'\)]f2[particle=\(\phi\)],
b--[anti fermion,reversed momentum=\(p_1-p_1'\)]a,
i1--[opacity=0]f1,
i2--[opacity=0]f2,
};
\hspace*{5mm}
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=i1 to a]{
f1[particle=\(\Bar{\psi}\)]--[anti fermion, momentum=\(p_2\)]b--[scalar]a1--[scalar, momentum'=\(p_2'\)]f2[particle=\(\phi\)],
i1[particle=\(\psi\)]--[fermion, momentum=\(p_1\)]a--[scalar]a1--[scalar, momentum=\(p_1'\)]i2[particle=\(\phi\)],
b--[anti fermion]a,
i1--[opacity=0]f1,
i2--[opacity=0]f2,
};

\end{center}
\vspace*{1cm}
\begin{center}
\feynmandiagram [layered layout, horizontal=a to b] {
% 
i1 [particle=\(\psi\)]
-- [fermion, momentum=\(p_1\)] a
-- [scalar] b
-- [scalar, momentum=\(p_1'\)] f1 [particle=\(\phi\)],
i2 [particle=\(\psi\)]
-- [anti fermion, momentum=\(p_2\)] c
-- [scalar] d
-- [scalar, momentum=\(p_2'\)] f2 [particle=\(\phi\)],
% 
{ [same layer] a -- [fermion] c },
{ [same layer] b -- [opacity=0] d},
};
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

And with option `xscale=1.5`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\feynmandiagram [layered layout, horizontal=a to b,xscale=1.5] {
% 
i1 [particle=\(\psi\)]
-- [fermion, momentum=\(p_1\)] a
-- [scalar] b
-- [scalar, momentum=\(p_1'\)] f1 [particle=\(\phi\)],
i2 [particle=\(\psi\)]
-- [anti fermion, momentum=\(p_2\)] c
-- [scalar] d
-- [scalar, momentum=\(p_2'\)] f2 [particle=\(\phi\)],
% 
{ [same layer] a -- [fermion] c },
{ [same layer] b -- [opacity=0] d},
};
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

output:
[image]